# Unable to use mysqli connection stored in an included file included in another file?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using mysqli for the first time in my procedural PHP application. Sorry for the complex hierarchy. Here's how it's structured.

**index.php** includes **config.php** includes **db_conn.php**
**index.php** includes **gallery.php**

**index.php**

```
include('config.php');

<html>
<body>
    <?php include('gallery.php');?>
</body>
</html
```

**config.php**

```
include('db_conn.php');
include('setttings.php')
#more code..
```

**db_conn.php**

```
?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

**gallery.php**

```
$sql_pa = "SELECT * FROM `pasal` WHERE `deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `datetime`";
$query_pa = mysqli_query($con, $sql_pa);
# more code...
```

So my connection is stored in variable ***$con*** located in the **db_conn.php** file which is unavailable in **gallery.php** file. How do I fix it?

Comment: You don't use `$con` in gallery. Did you even read your own code once?

Comment: It's a simple typo, you wrote `$conn` instead of `$con`.\

Comment: Minor error in the question. Edited it. My variable is the same ($con) throughout the application. Im still getting the error:  Undefined variable: con

Comment: Is it that we lose scope of a variable after a certain level of included files?

Comment: Come on, asking the same question over is not the way to go. Especially if no improvement is made.

Comment: Sorry about that, but my last question has had no replies for 12 hours despite edits!

Comment: You've got replies. VERY certain ones. Just make your real code like it shown in your sketch here, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

db_conn.php

```
$con
```

gallery.php

```
$conn
```

double N

Comment: Edited it. My variable is the same ($con) throughout the application. Im still getting the error: Undefined variable: con

Comment: Questions caused by a typo shouldn't be answered but voted to close instead.

Comment: Again, I've fixed the typo in the question. My connection variable is $con throughout the application.